# Spring Cloud API Gateway - spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id=true not working for urls - 404 Not Found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, api-gateway

I have an issue to call some urls from api gateway to one microservices.
Two urls shown below are not working and it throws 404 Not Found error.

```
http://localhost:8765/currency-conversion/currency-conversion/from/USD/to/INR/quantity/10
http://localhost:8765/currency-conversion/currency-conversion-feign/from/USD/to/INR/quantity/10
```

Here is the **application properties** file of **api gateway**

```
spring.application.name=api-gateway
server.port=8765
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost

# http://localhost:8765/CURRENCY-CONVERSION/currency-conversion/from/USD/to/INR/quantity/10 (Working)
# http://localhost:8765/CURRENCY-CONVERSION/currency-conversion-feign/from/USD/to/INR/quantity/10 (Working)
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true

# http://localhost:8765/currency-conversion/currency-conversion/from/USD/to/INR/quantity/10 (Not Working)
# http://localhost:8765/currency-conversion/currency-conversion-feign/from/USD/to/INR/quantity/10 (Not Working)
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id=true
```

Here is the **application properties** file of **currency-conversion-service**

```
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888
spring.application.name=currency-conversion
server.port=8100

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
```

Here is the **controller** class of **currency-conversion-service**

```
@RestController
public class CurrencyConversionController {


    @GetMapping("/currency-conversion/from/{from}/to/{to}/quantity/{quantity}")
    public CurrencyConversion calculateCurrencyConversion(
            @PathVariable String from,
            @PathVariable String to,
            @PathVariable BigDecimal quantity
    ) {
    }

    @GetMapping("/currency-conversion-feign/from/{from}/to/{to}/quantity/{quantity}")
    public CurrencyConversion calculateCurrencyConversionFeign(
            @PathVariable String from,
            @PathVariable String to,
            @PathVariable BigDecimal quantity
    ) {
    }

}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should have the property as follows:

```
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lowerCaseServiceId=true
```

So no dashes but camel case.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the name of microservices like below and it worked

From

spring.application.name=currency-exchange

To

spring.application.name=currency-exchange-ms

From

spring.application.name=currency-conversion

To

spring.application.name=currency-conversion-ms